# Как прибавить к дате сутки?

Tags: дата, java

```
Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
```

Вот я получил дату последнего изменения файла, как мне можно к этой дате прибавить 1 сутки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date tomorrow = new Date(lastModified.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
Date date = new Date();

Answer (score 2):

```
Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(lastModified); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
lastModified= c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй JodaTime. Очень упрощает работу с датами. Для добавления дня там есть метод plusDays(int days).